# Spring mvc @PathVariable not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am struggling for a hour to resolve the @pathvariable annotaton issue.

In my jsp,code looks like below

```
<td>
<spring:url value="/deleteEmployee.html" var="deleteEmployee">
</spring:url>
<a href="${deleteEmployee}/${employee.userID}"><img src="<c:url value="/images/delete.png" />" /></a>
</td>
```

In my controller i have a method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "deleteEmployee/{userId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
        System.out.println("userID::"+userId);
     return null;
}
```

But the controller was never getting called,always it is navigate to the 404 page

My URL looks like below:

```
http://localhost:8080/TaskMgmt/deleteEmployee.html/h776655
```

Please don't tag this question as duplicate since i searched all the URL before posting this question but i am not able to find a solution.

Spring version : 3.2.6

Also in my web.xml i have a below entry

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>taskMgmtServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please someone help me to resolve the issuse.

Comment: Shouldn't your URL be `.../TaskMgmt/deleteEmployee/h776655`?

Comment: Hi Rohit thank you for your comment.I hope you saw my servlet-mapping entry in the post.I mapped all my URL's using *,html so the URL you specified was not possible.

Comment: well, it should be then /TaskMgmt/deleteEmployee/h776655.html and not /TaskMgmt/deleteEmployee.html/h776655

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Url http://localhost:8080/TaskMgmt/deleteEmployee.html/h776655 not matching Spring Mvc Dispatcher Pattern *.html, it must finished by .html to be handled by Spring Mvc Dispatcher like this :
http://localhost:8080/TaskMgmt/deleteEmployee/h776655.html

Comment: @tcharaf...Sorry for the late comment.In my application if the URL contains pathvariable then it should not end with .html so what shall i do in my web.xml.Extremely sorry for not creating the new thread.

Comment: try this configuration, it should handle all requests by spring mvc dispatcher :
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>taskMgmtServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Thank You very much for your help!!